# Get rows from dataframe using index array from numpy where clause

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which has a column "Budget". I want to get all the rows from dataframe whose value corresponding to budget column is 0. I using this code:

```
dataFrameTrain.iloc[np.where(dataFrameTrain['budget']==0),:]
```

But, I am getting this exception:

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want do a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
dataFrameTrain[dataFrameTrain['budget']==0]
```